# How to enable terminal window to show for my command line tool when I run it from an app bundle?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line-tool, app-bundle

I'm trying to [notarize and staple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution?language=objc) my command line tool. Since mach-o binaries cannot be stapled, I decided to embed it into an app bundle. This works, except that when I run my command line tool by double-clicking the app bundle (`.app` directory, that I put it in) the terminal window is not shown.

Can I somehow make a terminal window display for my tool when I run it from an app bundle? (Similar to what would have happened if I double-clicked the mach-o binary file for my command line tool in Finder.)